# Selective replacement of NaN using column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
   GType   BNM  XXCV  COO
0  CAT1  WERT   NaN  NaN
1  CAT3  FRGT   NaN  NaN
2  CAT3   NaN   NaN  NaN
3  CAT2   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

I need to selectively replace the `NaN`s either with space or text `"vvv"` using the `GType`.

I have the following piece of code:

```
list1 = ['CAT1','CAT2']
mask = (df.COO.isnull()|df.BNM.isnull()|df.XXCV.isnull()) & (df.GType.isin(list1))
df.loc[mask, ('COO',  'BNM', 'XXCV')] = df.loc[mask, ('COO', 'XXCV', 'BNM'].replace('NaN', '')

list12 = ['CAT3']
mask12 =df.COO.isnull()|df.BNM.isnull())& (df.GType.isin(list12))
df.loc[mask12, ('COO',  'BNM')] = df.loc[mask12, ('COO', 'BNM')].replace('NaN', '')
```

It runs and changes the GType items in list1 and leaves the ones in list12. At the moment I get:

```
   GType   BNM XXCV  COO
0  CAT1  WERT          
1  CAT3  FRGT  NaN  NaN
2  CAT3   NaN  NaN  NaN
3  CAT2   NaN
```

My desired outcome would be:

```
   GType   BNM XXCV  COO
0  CAT1  WERT          
1  CAT3  FRGT  NaN  
2  CAT3         NaN 
3  CAT2
```

Where Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: what is your `list1`?

Comment: As detailed in the code

Comment: This looks possibly problematic: `df.loc[mask, ('COO',  'BNM', 'XXCV')] = df.loc[mask, ('COO', 'XXCV', 'BNM'].replace('NaN', '')` The paren before 'COO' is not balanced. It would be good to make this into a reproducible example.

Comment: Edited but still what is in list12 doesnt get its NaNs changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'GType': ['CAT1', 'CAT3', 'CAT3', 'CAT2'],
    'BNM': ['WERT', 'FRGT', None, None],
    'XXCV': [None, None, None, None],
    'COO': [None, None, None, None],
})

to_nan_xxcv = (df.XXCV.isnull()) & (df.GType.isin(['CAT1', 'CAT2']))
to_nan_rest = (df.COO.isnull() | df.BNM.isnull())
df.loc[to_nan_xxcv, 'XXCV'] = df.loc[to_nan_xxcv, 'XXCV'].fillna('')
df.loc[to_nan_rest, ('COO', 'BNM')] = df.loc[to_nan_rest, ('COO', 'BNM')].fillna('')
print(df)
```

The `to_nan_xxcv` will filtrate only what you want, and the rest will replace independently on the `GType`, which is apparently what you wanted based on desired output.
Also, you can replace by `vvv` by calling `.fillna('vvv')`